# How can I sum together object values in an array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

Let's say I have a few prices in an array of objects I want to sum together.
I have some code so far but I've never worked with objects in arrays before.

```
var total = 0;
var phones =
[
{
    name: 'Apple Iphone',
    price: 220000,
    provider: {
        country: 'HU',
        name: 'Vodafone'
    }
},

{
    name: 'Samsung Galaxy S10+',
    price: 340000,
    provider: {
        country: 'AUT',
        name: 'Telekom'
    }
},

{
    name: 'Huawei P30',
    price: 260000,
    provider: {
        country: 'GER',
        name: 'Vodafone'
    }
}
];

while (){
}

console.log(total);
```

Comment: SO is neither a code-writing nor tutorial service; I'd recommend finding a structured, introductory JS tutorial.

Comment: Thanks, maybe i can get something out of it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [reduce()](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_reduce.asp) javascript function. It's made for this kind of issues:

```js
var total = 0;
var phones =
[
{
    name: 'Apple Iphone',
    price: 220000,
    provider: {
        country: 'HU',
        name: 'Vodafone'
    }
},

{
    name: 'Samsung Galaxy S10+',
    price: 340000,
    provider: {
        country: 'AUT',
        name: 'Telekom'
    }
},

{
    name: 'Huawei P30',
    price: 260000,
    provider: {
        country: 'GER',
        name: 'Vodafone'
    }
}
];

total = phones.reduce((total, item) => {
  return total + item.price;
}, total);

console.log(total);
```

Comment: That's a lot more useful way to do it, thanks a lot. :)